# JQuery: убрать выбраный option из всех select

Tags: jquery

Делаю календарь добавления игр чемпионата по футболу.Выглядит все это так: 1-й select(команда хозяин) со списком всех команд - 2-й селект(команда гостей) со списком всех команд, и тд(таких селектов 14). Мне нужно исключить(удалить,блокировать) выбраную команду из других селектов, что бы не было повторений пар.

```
<select class="myselect" name="team_one_1">
        <option selected disabled value="0">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
        <option value="2">Днепр</option>
        <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
        <option value="4">Динамо</option>
        <option value="5">Волынь</option>
        <option value="6">Металлист</option>
        <option value="7">Говерла</option>
        <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
        <option value="9">Заря</option>
        <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
        <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
        <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
        <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
        <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
    <input type="text" name="datetime">
<select class="myselect" name="team_two_1">
    <option selected disabled>Выбрать</option>
    <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
    <option value="2">Днепр</option>
    <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
    <option value="4">Динамо</option>
    <option value="5">Волынь</option>
    <option value="6">Металлист</option>
    <option value="7">Говерла</option>
    <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
    <option value="9">Заря</option>
    <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
    <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
    <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
    <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
    <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
        <input type="hidden" name="tour" value="">
</div><br>
<select class="myselect" name="team_one_2">
        <option selected disabled value="0">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
        <option value="2">Днепр</option>
        <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
        <option value="4">Динамо</option>
        <option value="5">Волынь</option>
        <option value="6">Металлист</option>
        <option value="7">Говерла</option>
        <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
        <option value="9">Заря</option>
        <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
        <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
        <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
        <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
        <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
    <input type="text" name="datetime">
<select class="myselect" name="team_two_2">
    <option selected disabled>Выбрать</option>
    <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
    <option value="2">Днепр</option>
    <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
    <option value="4">Динамо</option>
    <option value="5">Волынь</option>
    <option value="6">Металлист</option>
    <option value="7">Говерла</option>
    <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
    <option value="9">Заря</option>
    <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
    <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
    <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
    <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
    <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
        <input type="hidden" name="tour" value="">
</div><br>
<select class="myselect" name="team_one_3">
        <option selected disabled value="0">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
        <option value="2">Днепр</option>
        <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
        <option value="4">Динамо</option>
        <option value="5">Волынь</option>
        <option value="6">Металлист</option>
        <option value="7">Говерла</option>
        <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
        <option value="9">Заря</option>
        <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
        <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
        <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
        <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
        <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
    <input type="text" name="datetime">
<select class="myselect" name="team_two_3">
    <option selected disabled>Выбрать</option>
    <option value="1">Черноморец</option>
    <option value="2">Днепр</option>
    <option value="3">Шахтер</option>
    <option value="4">Динамо</option>
    <option value="5">Волынь</option>
    <option value="6">Металлист</option>
    <option value="7">Говерла</option>
    <option value="8">Карпаты</option>
    <option value="9">Заря</option>
    <option value="10">Ильичевец</option>
    <option value="11">Ворскла</option>
    <option value="12">Металлург Д</option>
    <option value="13">Металлург З</option>
    <option value="14">Олимпик Д</option>
</select>
        <input type="hidden" name="tour" value="">
</div>
```

Делал что то вида:

```
$(".myselect").change(function() {
                                $("option :selected").remove();
                        });
```

Comment: @ager32, просто убрать - это не проблема. А если передумали, я ж так понимаю, что и назад вернуть нужно? Или это вам не важно?

Comment: не совсем понял ?

Comment: @ager32, там комментировать уже не могу, поэтому пишу тут. 

----------

Попробуйте сделать [вот так][1]. Только, если вы имена классов показали только для примера, а реальные отличаются, то и селекторы надо будет оформить соответствующе.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6SLX5/5/

Comment: Deonis, да оно, еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> не совсем понял ?

Я говорил о том, что убрать из всех списков команду - просто, но вам нужно её вернуть назад, если выбор был изменён? Просто ваш радикальный **.remove()**, говорит о том, что если уж выбрана команда, то назад пути уже не будет, изменить её уже нельзя.

Короче, [вот такое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6SLX5/3/) могу предложить. Если чаво не так - кричите.

```
var sel = $('.myselect'),
    opt = $('option:not(:first-child)', sel);

function review(){
    var chosen = sel.map(function(i, el){
        return $(':selected',el);
    });
    var teamId = 0;
    opt.show();
    chosen.each(function(i, el){
        teamId = $(el).val();
        opt.not(el).filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == teamId;
        }).hide();
    });
    return false;
}
sel.on('change',review);
```

**Stop!** Я совсем забыл, что в том же Chrome hide() на option не работает. Ща придумаем альтернативку.

**UPD** Проблемка была в другом месте, но протестируйте. Изменил код тут и ссылку на пример обновил

**UPD2** Для полной картинки - [используйте этот вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6SLX5/4/). Я ж совсем забыл про родного осла, а как же нам без него. [image]

Comment: @ager32, Вроде бы всё. Проверьте во всём, что можно и отпишитесь... самому интересно ;)

Comment: можно detach сделать предварительно записав в data() элемента информацию для возвращения.

Comment: @eicto, думал над этим, но мне показалось это более гемморойным. Для инвалида осла не очень хочется извращаться.

Comment: Спасибо большое, на счет вернуть назад должна быть такая возможность.

Comment: @ager32, не нужно нажимать "**наградить**", особенно, когда вы не такой богатый на баллы. Достаточно нажать "палец вверх" и, если вопрос вам кто-то дает исчерпывающий - жмём "галку" напротив того ответа.

Comment: мне больше интересно опции же всегда одни и те-же ? я бы тогда вообще на модель опирался и рендерил ее в соответсвии с текущим стэйтом

Comment: @eicto, наверно оно так и есть. Я ж предполагаю, что список команд в рамках какого-то одного чемпионата. Другое дело, если чемпионаты разные и команда может участвовать в нескольких...

Comment: @eicto, чемпионаты разные, команды все подгружаются из БД. Сначала думал добавлять по одной команде, два селекта после этого сделать кнопку Добавить еще и подгружать уже команды исключая выбранные. Но решил что так удобнее :), не знаю верно ли так, возможно учту ваш совет.

Comment: Deonis,а если допустим 14 селектов будут иметь класс .myselect, остальные 14 селектов класс .myselect2, еще 14 .myselect3 и тд.. Как можно тогда убирать команду только из селекта с определенным классом, а в других оставить команду.